# Find the number of users with one of multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to find the best way to count the number of Users who have one (or many) instances of a has_many relation.

For example, User `has_many :bank_accounts` and `:credit_accounts` (and a few other relations). I want to find the number of unique Users who have at least one bank_account and at least one credit_account, and ideally implement this inside of a scope so I can run where queries on it.

At the moment I'm implementing it (poorly) using the following code:

`(BankAccount.select(:user_id).uniq + CreditAccount.select(:user_id) + ...).uniq.count`

I've played around a lot with some joins, however I'm not getting any results. For example, I've toyed around a lot with different forms of `User.joins(:bank_accounts, :credit_accounts).uniq('users.id').count` however I don't appear to be getting any results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using normal sql. You can use the below query

```
select distinct(user_id) from 
(select user_id from bank_accounts union select user_id from credit_accounts) a;
```

I am not sure if a rails way exists for this.

Answer (score 0):

In this case all we need is an `INNER JOIN` of users with credit_accounts and bank_accounts.

```
User.joins(:credit_accounts, :bank_accounts).uniq.count
```

The above query works for me. The sql generated by this query is below

```
"SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(DISTINCT `users`.`id`) FROM `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `credit_accounts` ON `credit_accounts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` INNER JOIN `bank_accounts` ON `bank_accounts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`"
```

Comment: I played around a lot with a query like the one you mentioned, however never got it to work. 

For example `User.joins(:bank_accounts, :credit_accounts).uniq.count` returns 0. `User.joins(:bank_accounts).uniq.count` will return 1. `User.joins(:credit_accounts).uniq.count` returns 0, despite there being a CreditAccount.